# Modifying words occurences in pdffiles using pdfbox in a spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, pdfbox

I am trying modifying specific words occurrences in pdf files,so i try it in a spring boot app using apache pdfbox,i create a service to do this work then i use it an api finally i test this api with postman
those are my service and controller classes

```
public class PdfProcessingService {

    public boolean rechercherEtRemplacerPDF(String filePath, String recherche, String remplacement) {
        try {
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath));
            PDPage page = document.getPage(0);

            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            String texte = stripper.getText(document);

            if (texte.contains(recherche)) {
                texte = texte.replace(recherche, remplacement);

                stripper.setStartPage(0);
                stripper.setEndPage(document.getNumberOfPages());
                stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
                
             
                
                
                
                stripper.getText(document);

                document.save("/home/mohamed/Downloads/nouveau_fichier.pdf");
                document.close();

                System.out.println("Occurrence trouvée et remplacée ");
                return true; 
                } else {
                System.out.println("L'occurrence  n'a pas été trouvée.");
                return false; 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("erreur .");
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    
    @Autowired
    private  PdfProcessingService pdfProcessingService;

   
    
    @GetMapping("/process-pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<String> processPdf() {
        String filePath = "/home/mohamed/Downloads/invoice.pdf";
        String recherche = "#numConsultation";
        String remplacement = "12345";

        boolean processingResult = pdfProcessingService.rechercherEtRemplacerPDF(filePath, recherche, remplacement);

        if (processingResult) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Operation completed.");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("error .");
        }
    }
}
```

`

i didn't see any error everything is ok but in the generated pdf i didn't see any modification in the word i specify to be changed,please help!!!`

Comment: Your code doesn't replace any text in a PDF. It replaces text in a text **extraction** and then does nothing with it. And your second call of `stripper.getText(document);` does nothing.

Comment: See also https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#why-was-the-replacetext-example-removed%3F